# Axios not returning data from API in React Native Expo app on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I have issues with Axios not returning data from the API when I make a POST request to an API on my live server in my React Native Expo app **only** on iOS,

it sends the data successfully but it doesn't return any data returned from the server and it's causing issues in the app

It works well if I make GET request to the server it gets the data back from the server successfully

It also works well on Android, if I make POST requests on Android it works well and returns the data successfully, but it doesn't return any data on iOS

this is the Axios configuration

```js
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: APP_API_ENDPOINT,
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
        "Accept": 'multipart/form-data',
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        ...
    },
    
});
```

what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: try add `/` at the end of the `APP_API_ENDPOINT` like following `https://api.example/getdata/`

Comment: @Nightcrawler thanks for your response, I have gotten what's going wrong, it's the timeout, the timeout is too short, so I increased it to 90000, but I haven't tested all features sending POST data to the API endpoint, but most of the features breaking because of the issue has been fixed.